# How to send zero-value transactions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbfc

I'm working on code to export invoices from a custom application to QB using QBFC. My code is working in all cases except when the invoice in the custom application totals $0. (This can happen because there are offsetting items in the invoice.)

I've tried sending these invoices as invoices and as credit memos, but in either case, it fails with "Transaction amount must be positive."

Using QB interactively, I can create and save a zero-total invoice or credit memo. How can I make this work through QBFC?

Comment: Post the outgoing XML request you're sending and/or some example code. We do this all of the time, it works just fine for us.

Comment: I'm using the object model, not the XML version. Is there a way to easily see what XML is being generated?

Comment: See this page for enabling logging - https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=9&threadid=15902&enterthread=y

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the log helped me to see that the invoice that was failing had a discount I wasn't exporting. I tried another example with a zero total with no discounts and it worked as expected.